# Why is redirection important after dealing with POST data?

Tags: django, redirect

This code comes from the [Django documentation on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
try:
    selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    # Redisplay the poll voting form.
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'poll': p,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
    # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
    # user hits the Back button.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

I am learning the Django framework and I cannot understand why redirection is important for security after dealing with POST data.

Actually there is an explanation about it below:

> Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
>      with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
>      user hits the Back button.

Could someone explain this further?

Comment: See [Post/Redirect/Get - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: It's not for security - nothing in the pattern of sending a redirect after a successful post protects against a malicious user. It's for the convenience of your users, in particular protecting against some accidental double submissions or submissions in an unintended state as described in flasetru's link. I don't disagree with the reference - I just want to emphasize that for security, you must remember that any kind of request may be submitted with any data at all at any time, and your server-side application must handle potentially malicious data appropriately.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160574/should-i-use-httpresponseredirect-here

Answer (score 0):

It means user can posted many times by click `F5` or `(Back-Sumbit)(Back-Sumbit)(Back-Sumbit)`

If it is not return redirect?

I think it can help prevent irrigation.

Comment: I think, its a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, votes can be inserted into the database via `<int:question_id>/vote/`.

If the user submits POST data via a form to this url, and we return this same page as an `HttpResponse`, the POST contents will be remembered from the request and will be resubmitted. If they refresh this same page they were on, the contents of the POST will be also resubmitted. If they visit the vote page as a bookmark, and the browser remembers their POST data, another submission will be created. If the user presses the back button to get back to the vote page from somewhere else, and we return an `HttpResponse`, the POST data will be remembered, and another submission will occur. These will result in duplicate database entries.

If instead we use `HttpResponseRedirect` to send the user a view (like a results page for that question), the POST contents will not be transmitted to the new page.

An interesting aside for your example: If you were to respond with the same vote page  after submission via `HttpResponseRedirect`, the user would get a paragraph error message, as the details view & vote view serve different purposes (details shows the form, while vote handles POST data or lack thereof). However our POST data from our request will not carry over given we have used the correct method for this problem.